# How to insert values into a postgresql database with serial id using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a function that I use to update tables in PostgreSQL. It works great to avoid duplicate insertions by creating a temp table and dropping it upon completion. However, I have a few tables with serial ids and I have to pass the serial id in a column. Otherwise, I get an error that the keys are missing. How can I insert values in those tables and have the serial key get assigned automatically? I would prefer to modify the function below if possible.

```
def export_to_sql(df, table_name):
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    engine = create_engine(f'postgresql://{user}:{password}@{host}:5432/{user}')
    df.to_sql(con=engine,
              name='temporary_table',
              if_exists='append',
              index=False,
              method = 'multi')
    with engine.begin() as cnx:
        insert_sql = f'INSERT INTO {table_name} (SELECT * FROM temporary_table) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING; DROP TABLE temporary_table'
        cnx.execute(insert_sql)
```

code used to create the tables

```
CREATE TABLE symbols
(
 symbol_id serial NOT NULL,
 symbol    varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT PK_symbols PRIMARY KEY ( symbol_id )
);


CREATE TABLE tweet_symols(
    tweet_id  varchar(50)  REFERENCES tweets,
    symbol_id   int  REFERENCES symbols,
    PRIMARY KEY (tweet_id, symbol_id),
    UNIQUE (tweet_id, symbol_id)
);

CREATE TABLE hashtags
(
 hashtag_id serial NOT NULL,
 hashtag    varchar(140) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT PK_hashtags PRIMARY KEY ( hashtag_id )
);


CREATE TABLE tweet_hashtags
(
 tweet_id   varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 hashtag_id integer NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT FK_344 FOREIGN KEY ( tweet_id ) REFERENCES tweets ( tweet_id )
);

CREATE INDEX fkIdx_345 ON tweet_hashtags
(
 tweet_id
);
```

[image: example of the tables]

Comment: Can you share the `CREATE TABLE ` statements for the serial tables?  Is it that you want to create temp tables on the fly and then append the results to serial-id tables?

Comment: @snakecharmerb yes, but I only want to append the values. Right now I am querying the db to get the largest id and assign them manually through a list comprehension prior to the transfer. I'm sure there is a better way

Comment: "I have to pass the serial id in a column" -> why do you have to?  If you didn't pass an id the table would generate it automatically.

Comment: @snakecharmerb it expects data there so it reds the varchar column and states that it expected numbers but got text

Answer (score 1):

The `INSERT` statement does not define the target columns, so Postgresql will attempt to insert values into a column that was defined as `SERIAL`.

We can work around this by providing a list of target columns, omitting the serial types.  To do this we use SQLAlchemy to fetch the metadata of the table that we are inserting into from the database, then make a list of target columns.  SQLAlchemy doesn't tell us if a column was created using `SERIAL`, but we will assume that it is if it is a primary key and is set to autoincrement.  Primary key columns defined with `GENERATED ... AS IDENTITY` will also be filtered out - this is probably desirable as they behave in the same way as `SERIAL` columns.

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

def export_to_sql(df, table_name):
    engine = sa.create_engine(f'postgresql://{user}:{password}@{host}:5432/{user}')
    df.to_sql(con=engine,
              name='temporary_table',
              if_exists='append',
              index=False,
              method='multi')

    # Fetch table metadata from the database
    table = sa.Table(table_name, sa.MetaData(), autoload_with=engine)

    # Get the names of columns to be inserted,
    # assuming auto-incrementing PKs are serial types
    column_names = ','.join(
        [f'"{c.name}"' for c in table.columns 
         if not (c.primary_key and c.autoincrement)]
    )

    with engine.begin() as cnx:


        insert_sql = sa.text(
            f'INSERT INTO {table_name} ({column_names}) (SELECT * FROM temporary_table) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING; DROP TABLE temporary_table'
        )
        cnx.execute(insert_sql)
```